# Don't load information from Parse Again

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath, I load information from Parse into each cell. The only problem with this is every time I refresh a cell, the Parse information gets loaded again. Should I move the code out of the cellForRowAtIndexPath and put it somewhere else or should I surround it in an if statement? Please tell me if any more information or any code is needed. Thanks!

Here is my code to refresh...

```
func refresh() {
    print("View appeared")

    self.posts.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

    postQuery.whereKey("type", equalTo: "world")

    postQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            self.posts = objects

            self.table.reloadData()

        }

    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your data in `viewDidLoad`. Then access it in `cellForRowAtIndex`. Refresh the data in some other methods, maybe in pull down to fresh functionality, or a fresh button event.

Comment: Ok great thanks! It turns out that's not the problem I initially thought was causing the problem I'm trying to fix. What happens is I do exactly what you're saying but when I refresh a single cell using the .None row animation the image changes for a second. Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. Can you post the code you used? For refresh cell, I think you need something like startToUpdate, and finishUpdate

Comment: When one of my individual cells is refreshed the image sometimes changes to another image in the table for a millisecond.

Comment: Ummm, can you also show the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, particularly the part you load the image?

Comment: Yeah I just edited the post to have my entire cellForRow.

Comment: It's kind of long. However, if the image is only changed in this part of code, I do suspect it is due to `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` for the `postImage`. I haven't used `PFQuery` before, but you can to use a 'synchronized' way to get the image, rather than do it in background.

Comment: What would I do instead?

Comment: `getData` rather than the one you used. It all depends on how much data you want to pull out. If the size is not big, then doing it in background doesn't help the performance. If it is big, you need to try to load the 'actual' image later, by putting a placeholder image there first.

Comment: Ok I was able to fix it! I basically turned the data into an image and put that into an array in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Glad to here that. Note that this method is not feasible for a small number of images.

Comment: It will affect performance as the array of images are stored in memory. It also depends on how large is each single image. This is why normally data are loaded in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, this is called only the cell 'is going to' shown on screen.